# why kubernetes networking driver weave generating big log file

Tags: kubernetes, weave

I want to ask why the Kubernetes networking driver [weave](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/overview/) container is generating a lot of logs?

The log file size is 700MB after two days.

How can I solve that?

Comment: you cannot rotate/truncate this by native kubernetes. Perhaps,you may need to rotate it via docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Logs in kubernetes

As it was said in comment, kubernetes is not responsible for log rotation. This is from kubernetes documentation:

> An important consideration in node-level logging is implementing log
> rotation, so that logs don't consume all available storage on the
> node. Kubernetes is not responsible for rotating logs, but rather a
> deployment tool should set up a solution to address that. For example,
> in Kubernetes clusters, deployed by the kube-up.sh script, there is a
> logrotate tool configured to run each hour. You can also set up a
> container runtime to rotate an application's logs automatically.

As proposed option, this can be managed on container's runtime level.

Please refer to [Logging at the node level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level).

### Reducing logs for Weave CNI

There are two containers in each pod. Weave itself and weave-npc (which is a network policy controller).

By default weave's log level is set to INFO. This can be changed to WARNING to see only exceptions. This can be achieved by adding `--log-level` flag through the `EXTRA_ARGS` environment variable for the weave:

```
$ kubectl edit daemonset weave-net -n kube-system
```

So `weave container` part should look like:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - /home/weave/launch.sh
    env:
    - name: HOSTNAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    - name: EXTRA_ARGS # this was added with value below!
      value: --log-level=warning
    - name: INIT_CONTAINER
      value: "true"
    image: docker.io/weaveworks/weave-kube:2.8.1
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: weave
```

[Weave - logs level](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/#-reading-the-logs).

A lot of logs go from `Weave NPC`, there's an option that allows to `disable` NPC. However based on documentation this is a paid option based on their documentation - [cloud.weave.works](https://www.weave.works/product/cloud/)

[Weave - Changing configuration options](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/#-changing-configuration-options)

Comment: thanks, your anwser will be the solution, Can you please tell us how to change log level inside deployment.yaml ?

Comment: @karlos Sure. Please refer to my answer as I posted this initially. It may depend on how customized your `weave cni` is and how it was installed. General answer is to edit weave\s `daemon-set` by this command `kubectl edit daemonset weave-net -n kube-system` and final result how it should look like is in my answer as well (basically you will need to add 2 lines in `env`: `- name: EXTRA_ARGS` and `value: --log-level=warning`